# Accessing an array key in SASS

Tags: css, sass

I have a list in SASS, and I'm trying to access on of the items by using bracket notation:

```
$collection[1];
```

but that gives me an error.

Is there any other way to do this?

---

**Why do I want to do this?**

I have a list of colors that have to be set on different elements according to a colors assigned to them by the server. The markup has numbered classes (`color-0`, `color-1`, etc.). Here's the CSS I'm aiming for:

```css
.color-0 { color: red }
.color-1 { color: orange }
.color-2 { color: green }
.color-3 { color: blue }
/* many more, with more complex colors... */
```

Instead of writing it all by hand, I figured I could use a SASS collection with a loop:

```
$color-collection: ('red', 'orange', 'green', 'blue');
$color-count: length($color-collection);

@for $i from 0 to $color-count {
    .color-#{$i} {
        color: $color-collection[ $i ];
    }
}
```

but this just gives me the following error:

> Syntax error: Invalid CSS after "...color-collection": expected ";", was "[ $i ];"

---

**How can I accomplish this?**

Comment: Not exactly the same as your case, but method should prove useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14695965/sass-increment-a-class-and-choose-the-next-variable-in-a-list/14696447#14696447 (use @each)

Comment: @steveax - Ugh! That's exactly what I'm trying to avoid. I might potentially have upwards of 30 colors in there. Listing them all out twice like just makes me want to go right back to vanilla CSS; I think that's much neater.

Comment: you wouldn't have to list them out twice, just put the color names/values in `$color-collection` like you have them, and you and spin through them with @each. In the case of the question I linked, he needed them as vars too which you don't need. There's a few ways to skin that cat and bookcasey's answer is good.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
$color-collection: ('red', 'orange', 'green', 'blue');

@for $i from 0 to length($color-collection) {
    .color-#{$i} {
        color: unquote(nth($color-collection, $i+1));
    }
}
```

Use [`nth()`](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/Sass/Script/Functions.html#nth-instance_method), also `unquote()` if you want to pass quoted strings.

Though, I personally wouldn't:

```
$color-collection: (red, rgba(50,50,80, .5), darken(green, 50%), rgba(blue, .5));

@for $i from 0 to length($color-collection) {
    .color-#{$i} {
        color: nth($color-collection, $i+1);
    }
}
```

Because then you can pass any color object.

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I wanted (though I have no idea why you're using `length($color-collection)` in the `for` loop instead of the cached `$color-count`).

Comment: I suppose if you plan on using it in more than one place you could save it as a variable. :-)

Comment: Only point I would make is that it needs to be `from 1 to length($color-collection)`, as SASS' arrays start on `1` and not `0`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `@each` rule instead of `@for`, which is more semantic, faster, and it makes the code shorter:

```css
$color-collection: (red, orange, green, blue);

@each $color in $color-collection {
    .color-#{$color} {
        color: $color;
    }
}
```

Or if you prefer you can use `$color-collection` list directly into the `@each` directive:

```css
@each $color in red, orange, green, blue {
    .color-#{$color} {
        color: $color;
    }
}
```

As @bookcasey says is preferable to use *unquoted strings* because then you can pass any color object or function

[Sass reference for @each directive](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#each-directive)

Answer (score 3):

just came across this and tested bookcasey's answer, which works well but I wanted to use the color name as the class instead; I found that this code works as I needed.

```
$colors: ( 'black', 'white', 'red', 'green', 'blue' );

@for $i from 0 to length($colors) {
    $thisColor: unquote(nth($colors, $i+1));
    .color-#{$thisColor} {
        color: $thisColor;
    }
}
```

using the #{...} allows you to use functions as well, so if you need to use an arbitrary name that may not be used directly in the rules you could use

```
@for $i from 0 to length($colors) {
    .color-#{unquote(nth($colors, $i+1))} {
        // some rules that don't actually use the var
        // so there's no need to cache the var
    }
}
```

output:

```
.color-black { color: black; }
.color-white { color: white; }
.color-red { color: red; }
// etc..
```

Hope this helps someone else!

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem and tried Alex Guerrero solution. Didn't work form me cause output was like `.color-gray:{gray};` instead of `.color-1:{gray};`.So I modified it a bit and it looks like this:

```
$color-pallete: (gray, white, red, purple)

$i: 0
@each $color in $color-pallete
    .color-#{$i}
        color: $color
    $i: $i + 1
```

Oh, ye. I use SASS, not SCSS.