# Using @for in Sass to apply a list of colors to elements of the same type

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm using Bourbon, Neat, and Bitters for this project, and I'm getting a bunch of my code from Refills.

I have a list of colors that I need to apply to 6 different h2 elements respectively.

I have successfully done this in a similar fashion elsewhere in the project, but I'm having a hard time translating it here.

Everything I've tried has resulted in just the first color being applied to all h2 elements. If I add a number after the $i in nth, like `nth($colors, $i+1)`, it will apply the second color in the list to all of them.

Oddly, the CSS output is correct but the problem seems to be something to do with `nth-of-type`, because only the `nth-of-type(1)` appears.

Here's the important part of what I have so far:

```
.bullets {
  $icon-bullet-size: 3.5em;
  $colors:
      desaturate($logo-blue, 30),
      desaturate($logo-green, 10),
      desaturate($logo-yellow, 30),
      desaturate($badred, 30),
      desaturate($goldenrod, 30);

  padding: 2em;
  overflow: auto;
  margin-bottom: $base-line-height;
  text-align: center;


  h2 {
    @for $i from 1 to length($colors) {
      &:nth-of-type(#{$i}) {
        $color-from-list: nth($colors, $i);
        color: $color-from-list;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The h2 elements are nested a couple levels deep, like this:

```
<ul class="bullets">
<li class="bullet three-col-bullet">
  <div class="bullet-content">
    <h2>This needs to be one color</h2>
    <p>some content</p>
    </div>
</li>  
<li class="bullet three-col-bullet">
  <div class="bullet-content">
    <h2>This is a second color</h2>
    <p>content</p>
  </div>
</li>
<li class="bullet three-col-bullet">
  <div class="bullet-content">
    <h2>Radisson Hotel Salt Lake City</h2>
    <p>215 West South Temple<br>
      $129 USD—standard room<br>
      $139/$149 USD—triple/quad
    </p>
  </div>
</li>    
</ul>
```

And a good example of what I'm trying to accomplish [can be found here](http://refills.bourbon.io#er-toc-id-14)

I've referenced [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15079280/accessing-an-array-key-in-sass) as well and have tried the suggested solutions.

Where am I going wrong? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Cannot reproduce:  http://sassmeister.com/gist/1763036618303d481951

Comment: As @cimmanon has said your code seems to work as expected. Please, show us the extract of your CSS output.

Comment: Thanks @cimmanon, and Alex Guerrero. You're right. I narrowed it down some more and edited the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is incorrect.  The `:nth-of-type(n)` selector is for sibling elements.  None of your h2 elements are siblings of each other.  It is the li elements that are siblings, which the h2 elements are descendants of:

```
@for $i from 1 to length($colors) {
  li:nth-of-type(#{$i}) h2 {
    $color-from-list: nth($colors, $i);
    color: $color-from-list;
  }
}
```

http://sassmeister.com/gist/0b0c4793f58bc457c148

Comment: The loop should actually be `@for $i from 1 through length($colors) {` otherwise the last color won't be included. See https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/control/for for the difference between `to` and `through`.