# Automate CSS styles based on class name

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have many lines of CSS that essentially do the same thing over and over based on the class name:

```
.m45 {
    height: 90px;
}
.m50 {
    height: 100px;
}
.m55 {
    height: 110px;
}
.m60 {
...
```

Is there any way to automate this so that a class that matches `m` followed by any number `n` gets the style `height: calc(2px * n)`?

Comment: If these are sequential you could always use something like :nth-child() but I don't know anything for what you're trying to do.

Comment: with compiled CSS it is (using SASS or LESS).  If you haven't tried it out yet, I highly recommend it.  It makes a huge difference in efficiency and reliability.

Comment: Not with CSS. You could use a SASS or LESS mixin type thing but pure CSS. Nope.

Comment: Take a look at this answer using Sass http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14695965/sass-increment-a-class-and-choose-the-next-variable-in-a-list

Comment: If you're looking into using a preprocessing language such as SASS: yes, it is entirely possible :) http://sassmeister.com/gist/75770dbe813cecfb8dc3. Of course you can adjust the starting and ending integers to get the range you desire.

Answer (score 1):

No, CSS can't automate increases like this; it doesn't have support for functions like that. You can, however, use a CSS pre-processor like Sass to *write* shorter code that can handle things like a @for loop. Sass *compiles* into longer, normal CSS.